# Weceem 1.1.2 cannot find resources while starting up

Tags: grails, content-management-system, springsource, weceem

When I try to start project with Weceem I get following errors in STS console:

> | Error 2012-02-07 09:23:54,609 ["http-bio-8080"-exec-3] ERROR
>   resource.ResourceMeta  - While processing
>   /plugins/blueprint-0.9.1.1/css/blueprint/screen.css, a resource was
>   required but not found:
>   /plugins/blueprint-0.9.1.1/css/blueprint/src/grid.png
>
> | Error 2012-02-07 09:23:55,411 ["http-bio-8080"-exec-3] ERROR
>   resource.ResourceMeta  - While processing
>   /plugins/weceem-1.1.2/_weceem/css/weceem.css, a resource was required
>   but not found:
>   /plugins/weceem-1.1.2/_weceem/images/weceem/absBullet.png
>
> | Error 2012-02-07 09:25:32,772 ["http-bio-8080"-exec-10] ERROR
>   resource.ResourceMeta  - While processing
>   /plugins/ckeditor-3.6.0.0/js/ofm/styles/filemanager.css, a resource
>   was required but not found:
>   /plugins/ckeditor-3.6.0.0/js/ofm/images/circular/yes.png

I am using STS 2.9.0.M2, Grails version 2.0 and plugin for Weceem 1.1.2

Did anyone had a problem like this? I'm new to STS, Grails and Weceem so help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I found the solution, in case somebody runs to the same problem.
You just have to add following code into your Config.groovy file

grails.resources.adhoc.excludes = ['/plugins/weceem-1.1.2']